# Jade Syntax Highlighting Bug/Error in Sublime Text 2

Tags: syntax-highlighting, sublimetext2, pug

This screenshot was taken on Ubuntu 12.10 but it's also happening to a friend of mine on his MacBook Air.

It looks as though the program thinks the first single quotation mark is the end of a string while the second single quotation mark is the start of a new string. The odd part is: I have no single quotation marks before Line 26.

If I remove the word `chatbox` on Line 26, the highlighting is fine until Line 27 at `'chatinput'`. Changing the single quotations to double quotations didn't help either.

[image: jade syntax highlighting]

Comment: same goes for `script \n \t test('blah'){}` - the problem is with the first instance of `('` inside the `script` block.

Comment: and `window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're using the version of the syntax from the Package Control.

The solution is to get one of the [latest versions](https://github.com/miksago/jade-tmbundle/network) of the Syntax Bundle from the GitHub, I've chosen [this fork](https://github.com/davidrios/jade-tmbundle/) and everything works ok now.

Comment: If the latest `davidrios` version is better, shouldn't we update package control's known packages so that everyone gets the fix next time they start ST2?: https://github.com/wbond/package_control_channel/blob/master/repositories.json

Answer (score -1):

What I meant, is that to declare a javascript function in jade, it is of the form

```
script(type="text/javascript"). // a point at the end of the line
   var chatbox = document.getElementById("chatbox');
   var BASE_URL = '#{BASE_URL}' //Pass some environment variable
   var socket = io.connect(BASE_URL)
```

Comment: Could you post this in English, please!?

Comment: He said, "You are missing the period (`script` vs `script.`). They don't behave the same." Note: I haven't tested the suggestion but I don't think it's the correct solution _and_ using `script` without the period used to be the correct syntax.